# ModuleNotFoundError while importing requests and sherlock

Tags: python, unix, owasp

I am getting this error when I am using sherlock on my Debian machine

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/root/data/sherlock/sherlock/__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import sherlock
  File "/root/data/sherlock/sherlock/sherlock.py", line 18, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Comment: Did you run these commands: `pip install sherlock` and `pip install requests` on the terminal/shell before importing them?

Comment: i got this error => error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pylibmc

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the required dependencies listed in the `requirements.txt` file ? They are required to run Sherlock.

You may install with by running this command :

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```